# I make a 3-tier application i want to insert the data in table it show me a error...it show me a null exception

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-to-vb.net

DataBase Layer...................

```
public static void AddEnrollment(StudentScore enrollment)
{
       SqlConnection conn = MyDB.GetConnection();

       string insertStm = "insert into EnrollmentTable (StudentID,CourseID,DateEnrolled,Score) values (@StudentID,@CourseID,@DateEnrolled,@Score)";

       SqlCommand insertComm = new SqlCommand(insertStm, conn);

       insertComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StudentID", enrollment.EnrollmentData.StudentData.StudentID);
       insertComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CourseID", enrollment.EnrollmentData.CourseData.CourseID);
       insertComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateEnrolled", enrollment.EnrollmentData.DOE);
       insertComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Score", enrollment.Score);

       try
       {
           conn.Open();
           insertComm.ExecuteNonQuery();
       }
       catch (SqlException sqlex)
       {
           throw sqlex;
       }
       finally
       {
           conn.Close();
       }
```

Business Layer...............

```
public class StudentScore
{
    public Enrollment EnrollmentData { get; set; }
    public int Score { get; set; }

    public StudentScore()
    {
    }

    public StudentScore(Enrollment aEnrollmentData, int aScore)
    {
        EnrollmentData = aEnrollmentData;
        Score = aScore;
    }
}
```

Presentation Layer..................

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        StudentScore enrollment = new StudentScore();

        enrollment.EnrollmentData.StudentData.StudentID = comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString();
        enrollment.EnrollmentData.CourseData.CourseID = comboBox2.SelectedValue.ToString();
        enrollment.EnrollmentData.DOE = DateTime.Now;

        EnrollmentDB.AddEnrollment(enrollment);

        MessageBox.Show("Student is enrolled this course.");
    }
```

It show me this error

> Exception : enrollment.EnrollmentData.StudentData.StudentID =
>   comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString();

Please help me how do I fix it?

Comment: What is the actual exception you are getting NullException ?

Comment: yeah it shows NullException.....

Comment: Can you show the stacktrace ?

Comment: It shows EnrollmentData is null....

Comment: Yes can we see a stacktrace ?

Comment: When you see the exception there will be a bunch of text after it copy that and paste it here

Comment: OR look at ex.stacktrace

Comment: Can i show u run time error pic....

Answer (score 1):

`enrollment.EnrollmentData` has not been initialized. In the absence of further details, change

```
StudentScore enrollment = new StudentScore();
```

to

```
StudentScore enrollment = new StudentScore(new Enrollment(), 0);
```

Comment: @user1050667: Please show the definition of the `Enrollment` class.

Comment: In Erollment class i am taking StudentData from Student Class and CourseData fom Course Class and Date of Enrollment Variable in DOE..

Comment: @user1050667: Please *show the definition* of the `Enrollment` class.